# Securing userPassword access with OpenLDAP in RHEL

Tags: ldap, openldap, pam

I have set up an OpenLDAP server on RHEL 5.4, and am configuring other servers to authenticate against it.  I have both ldap with StartTLS and ldaps configured and working.

On my client machines, my **/etc/nsswitch.conf** includes:

```
passwd:     files ldap
shadow:     files ldap
group:      files ldap
```

I can successfully log in to a client with a user that is only defined in LDAP (i.e. its not finding it in /etc/passwd, and is successfully asking LDAP for user info, and authenticating against the password hash stored in LDAP).

My problem is when I try to lock down access to attributes in the LDAP server, specifically, in **/etc/openldap/slapd.conf**, ldap users can no longer log in:

```
access to attrs=userpassword
        by self write
        by anonymous auth
        by * none
```

I'm logging slapd, and it appears (my interpretation, correct me if I'm wrong) that pam_ldap is attempting to **read** all the attributes in the poxixAccount objectClass:

```
    filter: (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=cthompson))
    attrs:
  uid
  userPassword
  uidNumber
  gidNumber
  cn
  homeDirectory
  loginShell
  gecos
  description
  objectClass
```

In my openldap logging, I get no access or acl errors, but I do get:

```
access_allowed: search access to "uid=cthompson,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com" "objectClass" requested
access_allowed: search access to "uid=cthompson,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com" "uid" requested
```

Is there something that needs to be configured so instead of reading the userPassword attribute, pam_ldap tries to "auth" against it (so the requests gets handled by the "by anonymous auth" access rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pam_ldap` shouldn't be attempting to read the userPassword value to log you in -- It logs you in by doing an LDAP bind with the DN that it retrieves.

It's possible the search parameters pam_ldap uses are over-broad & it tries to pull userPassword as a result, but if your ACL is set up correctly (looks fine to me) it won't get that value in its results.

---

Just in case your ACLs *aren't* fine (I've been known to miss stupidly obvious stuff before), here's the working ACL list from my production LDAP environment :)

```
# Access and Security Restrictions
# (Most restrictive entries first)
access to attrs=userPassword
    by self write
    by dn.sub="ou=sync,dc=mydomain,dc=com" read
    by anonymous auth
by users none

access to * by * read
```

The trailing `access to * by * read` is important,  I didn't see it in your examples so I'm not sure if it's missing or just omitted from your snippet.

The `sync` line is for my LDAP synchronization service and isn't necessary if you're not doing replication...

Comment: I actually had 
access to *
       by self write
       by users read
       by * none
instead of "access to * by * read".  Obviously the "by * none" was what was causing my issue.  I'd often commented that out, in which case I was missing the "access to * ...", which, as you mention, is important (I didn't know that - so thinks for the info).  Adding that worked.  Thanks!